# Spock: Parameterized test in a loop

Tags: groovy, junit, spock

In JUnit, multiple test cases can be executed in a loop with:
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)

How can this be achieved in Spock?

Comment: With [data tables](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/data_driven_testing.html), or exactly how you show in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327603/spock-how-to-run-a-set-of-methods-as-a-single-test-repeatedly

Comment: @tim_yates: Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to run multiple tests against the same sets of data, you could do something like the following:

```
@Shared
def numOnes = [1, 2]
@Shared
def numTwos = [1, 3]

@Unroll("When I add #numOne and #numTwo then the response is #resultNum")
def "Simple addition test"() {
    when:
    int response = numOne + numTwo
    then:
    response == resultNum
    where:
    numOne << numOnes
    numTwo << numTwos
    resultNum << [2, 5]
}

@Unroll("When I take #numOne away from #numTwo then the response is #resultNum")
def "Simple subtraction test"() {
    when:
    int response = numTwo - numOne
    then:
    response == resultNum
    where:
    numOne << numOnes
    numTwo << numTwos
    resultNum << [0, 1]
}
```

**NOTE** Only `@Shared` and static fields can be access from a `where` block. Shared simply states that the field can be accessed by all defs in the file.

Comment: Thank you. But my question was a bit different. If I have several def for a single test, how you can iterate for different sets of data? I mean for each set of data, how you can execute multiple defs?